# Bash alias name from a variable

Tags: bash, function, alias

Is there a way to make a bash alias (or function) with its name coming from a variable?

For instance, is it possible to do something along these lines:

```
create_alias_with_name() {
  alias $1="echo a custom alias"
}
```

Or something along these lines:

```
create_func_with_name() {
  $1() {
    "echo inside a function with a variable name"
  }
}
```

In other words, I would prefer to have some kind of function "factory" that can register functions for me. Is this possible or beyond the capabilities of Bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you even try it?  Your first example works fine.

You can make the second work by adding an `eval`:

```
create_func_with_name() {
  eval "$1() {
    echo inside a function with a variable name
  }"
}
```

Comment: Of course I tried it out before posting... if it had worked I wouldn't have posted!

It didn't work then, and it doesn't work now. Are you sure the first example works fine? When I run it and try the command, I get "command not found errors".

However, thanks for fixing up the second snippet. That works great for me, thank you very much!!

Comment: I copied & pasted your example into my terminal and it worked fine.  Still does.  I'm on a mac, so I'm sure my bash version is old: "GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.".

Comment: Hmm, I am running "GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 2011" so actually not that much newer. Ah well - I guess the lesson is that aliases are less reliable than functions.

Answer (score 0):

just in case, one may use a variable both as a part of the alias name and as a part of the alias command:

```
alias foo${var1}="bar${var2}"
```